# Adding defaultdicts together on key then dividing them

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary of 1000+ default dicts, I want to iterate through each default dict, sum them up on key and then divide by the count to get the average value per key.

Each default dict has the same keys, i.e.

```
{'A': 0.0, 'B': 1.0, 'C': 1.0, 'D': 1.0, 'E': 1.0}
{'A': 2.0, 'B': 1.2, 'C': 3.0, 'D': 1.0, 'E': 3.0}
```

I want the following to be my output

```
{'A': 1.0, 'B': 1.1, 'C': 2.0, 'D': 1.0, 'E': 2.0}
```

How do I iteratively add default dicts up, and then divide them, a la row operations in a DataFrame? Or is there a better way to be doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Is it relevant at all that those are defaultdicts?

Comment: Nah, that's just how I read them in, I could read them in as something else I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using a dictionary comprehension with `sum`:

```
d1 = {'A': 0.0, 'B': 1.0, 'C': 1.0, 'D': 1.0, 'E': 1.0}
d2 = {'A': 2.0, 'B': 1.2, 'C': 3.0, 'D': 1.0, 'E': 3.0}
dicts = {"d1": d1, "d2": d2}
n = len(dicts)
res = {k: sum(d[k] for d in dicts.values()) / n for k in d1}
# {'A': 1.0, 'B': 1.1, 'C': 2.0, 'D': 1.0, 'E': 2.0}
```

Note: This is assuming that, as you wrote in the question, all the dicts have *the same* keys, or are `defaultdicts`, so that missing keys don't cause an error.

Answer (score 4):

You can simplify this a bit using `collections.Counter`:

```
summed_dict = collections.Counter()
for d in partial_dicts:
    summed_dict.update(d)

# Use .viewitems or .iteritems instead of .items on Py2
average_dict = {k: v / len(partial_dicts) for k, v in summed_dict.items()}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`pandas.Series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html) to perform the *averaging* of both dictionary values, then convert the series back to a dictionary:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.Series({'A': 2.0, 'B': 1.2, 'C': 3.0, 'D': 1.0, 'E': 3.0})
b = pd.Series({'A': 0.0, 'B': 1.0, 'C': 1.0, 'D': 1.0, 'E': 1.0})
c = ((a+b)/2).round(1)
print(c.to_dict())
# {'A': 1.0, 'B': 1.1, 'D': 1.0, 'E': 2.0, 'C': 2.0}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your data as a dict of dicts, then this is how I would do it (pretty functional approach):

```
d = {1: {'A': 0.0, 'B': 1.0, 'C': 1.0, 'D': 1.0, 'E': 1.0},
 2: {'A': 2.0, 'B': 1.2, 'C': 3.0, 'D': 1.0, 'E': 3.0}}

import functools

def add_dicts(d1, d2):
    return {k:d1[k]+d2[k] for k in d1}

dsum = functools.reduce(add_dicts, d.values())

N = len(d.keys())
davg = {k:v/N for k,v in dsum.items()}
print(davg)
```

Output:

```
{'C': 2.0, 'E': 2.0, 'A': 1.0, 'B': 1.1, 'D': 1.0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over one dictionary's keys and values and add the value to the value of the corresponding key in the other dictionary.
Example:

```
dict1 = {'A': 0.0, 'B': 1.0, 'C': 1.0, 'D': 1.0, 'E': 1.0}
dict2 = {'A': 2.0, 'B': 1.2, 'C': 3.0, 'D': 1.0, 'E': 3.0}
for key,value in dict1.iteritems():
    dict2[key] = (value + dict2[key]) / 2
print dict2 # prints {'A': 1.0, 'B': 1.1, 'C': 2.0, 'D': 1.0, 'E': 2.0 }
```

For simplicity, you may just create a new dictionary as well:

```
dict1 = {'A': 0.0, 'B': 1.0, 'C': 1.0, 'D': 1.0, 'E': 1.0}
dict2 = {'A': 2.0, 'B': 1.2, 'C': 3.0, 'D': 1.0, 'E': 3.0}
dictAns = dict()
for key,value in dict1.iteritems():
    dictAns[key] = (value + dict2[key]) / 2
print dictAns # prints {'A': 1.0, 'B': 1.1, 'C': 2.0, 'D': 1.0, 'E': 2.0 }
```

Comment: Why do you iterate the items` it seems you are only using the key.

Comment: @tobias_k: Well, they could save a lookup by replacing `dict1[key]` with `value`.

Comment: What if I have more than two dictionaries?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. If you have more than 2 dicts you will have to add each dict item separately like `value + dict2[key] + dict3[key] + .../ num of dicts`. If instead, you have a list of dicts, you can simply iterate over them in an inner for loop and add them to average then divide average by number of dicts.